# Magento 2 Reindex process isn't working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, reindex

Without any reason my site stopped working. I've been trying to start the reindexing process, but it isn't working, only "Design Config Grid" can be reindexed:

```
user@serv [~/public_html]# php bin/magento indexer:status
Design Config Grid:                                Reindex required
Customer Grid:                                     Reindex required
Category Products:                                 Reindex required
Product Categories:                                Reindex required
Product Price:                                     Reindex required
Product EAV:                                       Reindex required
Stock:                                             Reindex required
Catalog Rule Product:                              Reindex required
Catalog Product Rule:                              Reindex required
Catalog Search:                                    Reindex required
user@serv [~/public_html]# bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product
user@serv [~/public_html]# php bin/magento indexer:status
Design Config Grid:                                Reindex required
Customer Grid:                                     Reindex required
Category Products:                                 Reindex required
Product Categories:                                Reindex required
Product Price:                                     Reindex required
Product EAV:                                       Reindex required
Stock:                                             Reindex required
Catalog Rule Product:                              Reindex required
Catalog Product Rule:                              Reindex required
Catalog Search:                                    Reindex required
user@serv [~/public_html]# bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
user@serv [~/public_html]# bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock
user@serv [~/public_html]# php bin/magento indexer:status
Design Config Grid:                                Ready
Customer Grid:                                     Reindex required
Category Products:                                 Reindex required
Product Categories:                                Reindex required
Product Price:                                     Reindex required
Product EAV:                                       Reindex required
Stock:                                             Reindex required
Catalog Rule Product:                              Reindex required
Catalog Product Rule:                              Reindex required
Catalog Search:                                    Reindex required
user@serv [~/public_html]# php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
user@serv [~/public_html]#
```

Any idea what should I do next? And what is the reason of this issue?

Comment: I think rest are stuck in processing state. Can you check it in admin what is the status showing?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I can't login to admin page. The site shows me a blank page. I didn't see any error message in logs files.

Comment: Can you check the permissions? Also delete some files manually through ftp and then try. Needs to delete the files var/cache, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed, var/log, var/report, pub/static/frontend, pub/static/adminhtml, generated/code, generated/metadata. After that run setup:upgrade, di compile, static content deploy and set the permissions properly and see if it works.

Comment: @SukumarGorai I have tried to do everything that you wrote and there is no changes.

Comment: Then need to debug the code and check whats the actual issue. Also you can check apache log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of Fatal errors in my "error_log" file:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /home/sellastu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

So I opened my "php.ini" file and clear comment before this line:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

After activation this extension reindex works fine.